# Angular2 ngFor not working

Tags: javascript, angular, atom-editor, ngfor

I am trying to implement a basic shopping list, but my ngFor in Angular is not working.

```js
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
  template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><ul><li *ngFor="let i of items"><span>{{i}}</span></li></ul>'

})
export default class MyAppComponent {
  title = 'ShoppinList';
  items = ['Milk','Ham','Eggs'];
}
```

The only thing that appears is "loading..." and I am getting more than 10 cryptic errors.

[image]

Comment: Your component should contain the `template` and @`View` can be removed. Your `import` statement is not correct. Maybe you are copy/pasting from an old beta version?

Answer (score 2):

Without trying it first I noticed an error in the import statement at the top. Should be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
```

Answer (score 1):

`@View()` was removed almost a year ago. If you see examples that use it, just move the content to the `@Component()` decorator while `directives` and `pipes` were moved from `@Component()` to `@NgModule()`s `declaration`.

You need to add `CommonModule` to `@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule], ...}) export class SomeModule{}` in every module where you want to use `ngFor` (or other directives shippled with Angular - `BrowserModule` already includes `CommonModule`).

Answer (score 1):

its good way to use ngIf and use your template inside your component properties.

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template : '<div>
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <ul *ngIf="items">
          <li *ngFor="let i of items"><span>{{i}}</span></li>
      </ul>
  </div>'
})

export default class MyAppComponent {
  title : string =  'ShoppinList';
  items : Array<string> =  ['Milk','Ham','Eggs'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `@View` here.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{title}}
      <ul><li *ngFor="let i of items"><span>{{i}}</span></li></ul>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class App {
  title = 'ShoppinList';
  items = ['Milk','Ham','Eggs'];
}
```

**[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nS0zYUBxJp5PuGLcmBCU?p=preview)**